# Use recursion to find a specific character followed by another specific character in a char[]

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, char

Looking to return the amount of times in a char array the char ':' is followed by the char ')' using recursion.

```
public class Recursion {
public static int countSmiles(char[] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length == 0) return 0;
        if(String.valueOf(numbers[0])== ":" && String.valueOf(numbers[1])==")") return 1 + countSmiles(numbers[1]);
        return countSmiles(numbers[1]);
    }
public static void main (String[] args) {
        char[] s = {'n','g', ':' ,')', ':' ,')'};
        System.out.println(countSmiles(s));
    }
}
```

I expect the out put to be 2.

I was able to do this successfully using a String (see below) but unable to do so with the char array.

```
public static int countSmiles(String numbers) {
    if (numbers.length() == 0) return 0;
    if (numbers.charAt(0) == ':'&& numbers.charAt(1)==')') return 1 + countSmiles(numbers.substring(1));
    return countSmiles(numbers.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition from what people said about `Arrays.copyOfRange()`, you need also makes equality with `String.equals()` instead of `==`.

Working code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
  public static int countSmiles(char[] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length == 0) return 0;
        if(String.valueOf(numbers[0]).equals(":") && String.valueOf(numbers[1]).equals(")")) {
            return 1 + countSmiles(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length));
        }

        return countSmiles(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length));
    }
  public static void main (String[] args) {
        char[] s = {'n','g', ':' ,')', ':' ,')'};
        System.out.println(countSmiles(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`numbers[1]` will get you the second character and the compiler will tell you that argument is not correct, since an `chars[]` is expected and you just giving it `char`. You need to do a sub-array Arrays.copyOfRange and pass it into countSmiles

```
return countSmiles(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length - 1));
```

However for more elements you will need to keep the counter of how many elements you have skipped so far and use it instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers[1]` is just a single char not the whole array without the first char. To get that you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length)`.

Answer (score 0):

First your Recursion is never moving.

- How are you supposed to scan all that array without a pointer?
- You never compare Strings with `==` in java use `equals`
- Second you can compare chars without casting again to string

public static int countSmiles(char[] numbers,int index) {

```
if ( numbers.length-2 < index) return 0;

if(numbers[index]==':' && numbers[index+1]==')')
return 1 + countSmiles(numbers,index+1);

return countSmiles(numbers,index+1);
```

}
    //Main Class

```
       public static void main (String[] args) {
            char[] s = {'n','g', ':' ,')', ':' ,')','r','5'};
            System.out.println(countSmiles(s,0));
        }
```

Try with this and it will run.